# Delaunay face triangulation OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, delaunay

I am trying to follow [this conversation about the delaunay triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603780/delaunay-triangulation-opencv-c) but I can't have the same result that axel had in the picture. I really want to know how to draw the mesh only on the face? 
I also need to know what is the role of this loop and what is the type of "point" exactly?

Can anyone please help me. Thank you :)

```
for(int i = 0; i < point.getDim(); ++i)
            {
              Point2f fp(point.getCoord()[i].real(), point.getCoord()[i].imag());
              subdiv.insert(fp);
            }
```

Comment: I can't  help you with opencv but the declaration of the point object is not given in the original post. I assume its of the type Point.

Comment: The post you link to doesn't contain enough information to answer your question. `point` appears to be user-defined, so there's no good way of knowing what it is. It appears that this code is initializing the initial point set to be triangulated. You'll probably find it more useful to post your own code, and explain why your results are different from what you expect.