# Facial expression recognition from webcam

Tags: opencv, expression, webcam, face-detection, feature-detection

I am currently working on a project where I have to extract the facial expression of a user (only one user at a time from a webcam) like sad or happy.

There are a lot of programs/APIs to do face detection but I did not find any one to do automatic expression recognition.

The best possibility I found so far:

I used OpenCV for face detection earlier, which was working great, so If anyone has some tips on how to do it with OpenCV, that would be great!

Some user on a OpenCV board suggested looking for AAM (active apereance models) and ASM (active shape models), but all I found were papers.

-So i'm Using Active Shape Models with [Stasm](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/), which will give me access to 77 different points within the face, so I would still have to manually map them to expressions.

Any programming language is welcome.

Comment: Do you have any progress with your project?

Comment: @NenadBulatovic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640804/facial-expression-classification-in-real-time-using-svm

Answer (score 3):

After 2.4 release, opencv came with a face recognition API. You may define sad and happy faces as two different faces and use [the API](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/) to classify them. If you are looking for any tutorials you can check out [opencv's tutorial page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html), too.

Comment: if i will use this api i must get for every user the happy and the sad face !!

Comment: Yes, those are pre defined. Maybe you can create your own training pattern for face detection. Train for happy faces and sad faces in 2 different xml files, and try using them.

Comment: my target is to any user will use this application and is this method will be fast to use on webcam videos !!

Comment: You said you tried face detection using opencv (using the .xml file that comes together with opencv package), wasn't it fast enough? I tried it also within a skin detector, algoritm complexity was much more but it was working fast enough.

Comment: ok could you give me a tutorial about how to train xml file for opencv

Comment: http://opencvuser.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html , http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

Comment: also try [delaunay triangulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603780/delaunay-triangulation-opencv-c), as it is used to recognize expressions, too.

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı Do you have a website or is there any way I can contact you directly?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://www.wvc2011.ufpr.br/anais_wvc_2011.pdf) article can help you.

It is explanation of concepts used to achieve result shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6xNqPPSKtM):

Also, you might want to have a look [here](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~rvalenti/projects/mmis/Automatic%20Facial%20Emotion%20Recognition.pdf).

All of above mentioned is a work of people who more or less achieved what you watn.

I want to do same as you - facial expression recognition with OpenCV, so I hope sooner or later we can exchange our ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Half the problem is solved for you using OpenCV. If you built OpenCV with examples, you can run an example named **c-example-smiledetect** which can detect a smiling face with different levels.

The code should be in you OpenCV folder under **samples/c**. i recall you can adjust the sensitivity in the code so that might help. You can also find the code [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/c/smiledetect.cpp).

On another note, an implementation of AAM using OpenCV can be found in [this book](http://www.packtpub.com/cool-projects-with-opencv/book) (chapter 7). This doesn't include the searching and fitting part though, just shows how to create an AAM from ASM and a texture.

Comment: c-example-smiledetect is using pre trained Haar detector. I think that OP must train his own detectors (classifiers) in order to detect other facial expressions. If I recall correctly it is necessary to use several thousands images to do so. I rad and article where people said that on fast machines whole training process took more than non - stop 7 days for a classifier to be created. Then if it shows bad results, re-training must be applied.